# How to change the button fontsize without changing button size (in android)?

Tags: android, button, resize, font-size

I need to have a grid (created by program, not by xml) 
of equally sized buttons. They display text in different sizes.
The problem is that when I change the text size to a smaller size,
then the button automatically resizes to be smaller than the others.

Thanks,

Note: the grid is created adding *TableRow*s of buttons to 
a *TableLayout*. The buttons are created and added to a *TableRow*

```
tr.addView(bu, 36, 45);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use gridview if you want to display a grid?

Comment: I don't truly know. Visually I've got the desired effect (but having the problem when changint fontsize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding padding (`setPadding()`) will expand the button while keeping the font size small. Figuring out how much padding to add, though, is up to you.